# Is Medea secretly the old woman and the Talking Oaken Image in Nathaniel Hawthorne's "Tanglewood Tales: The Golden Fleece"?

Tags: hera, medea

Medea, the enchantress, said to Jason:

> I could tell you, if I pleased, who was the old woman with the
> peacock, the pomegranate, and the cuckoo staff, whom you carried over
> the river; and, likewise, who it is that speaks through the lips of
> the oaken image, that stands in the prow of your galley.

My friends and I can't seem to agree on whether Medea was slyly telling Jason that she was actually, secretly, the old woman (who is Hera, the Queen of the gods) and the Oaken Image, or if she was just bragging about how powerful of an enchantress she was.

Also at the end of the chapter, after Jason had retrieved the Golden Fleece, Medea, who had come with Jason to find the Golden Fleece, was not to be seen, but the old woman appeared. She was extremely excited that Jason had found the Golden Fleece but then she disappeared into the shadows.

After that the oaken image on the Argo said, "Make haste, prince Jason. For your life, make haste!" Does that indicate that Medea turned back into the old woman, disappeared, and then went to the ship?